# What is Homebrew? Is it similar to Anaconda?

Tags: python

I have Python3 installed, along with Anaconda. I thought this was great, because Anaconda came with packages I use. I came across a library that wasn't able to be installed using pip, it required **Homebrew**. Can someone please explain what **Homebrew** is? Is it mutually exclusive, or is **Homebrew** a supplemental tool that will go along with my Python3 and **Anaconda** that I already installed? Please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

Homebrew is a package manager for system programs and libraries, similar to what pip does for python modules and conda (without the environment managing aspect). You can think of it as a command-line app store which lets you install various command-line programs and libraries.

They can coexist, but note that you get the following warning if you've installed both when you get homebrew's diagnostics via the command: `brew doctor` (Homebrew v.1.2.0):

> Warning: Anaconda is known to frequently break Homebrew builds,
>   including Vim and MacVim, due to bundling many duplicates of system
>   and Homebrew-available tools.
>
> If you encounter a build failure please temporarily remove Anaconda
>   from your $PATH and attempt the build again prior to reporting the
>   failure to us. Thanks!